# How can I convert a [String: Any] dictionary into a double?

Tags: swift, firebase

[MyCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSBmy.png)

How can I convert a `[String: Any]` dictionary into a double?

I am using the firebase database, and I want to return the date of the posts, in the timeline of my app, but I am not able to convert the saved data into the database "String" in "Double".

```
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()
databaseRef.child("posts").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in
if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
    let textPost = dict["post_message"] as! String
    let photoUrlString = dict["photoUrl"] as! String
    let userIDPost = dict["userIDPost"] as! String
    let datePost = dict["datePost"] as! Double
```

Comment: You probably need to cast your datePost as Date object, what value are you expecting to get from dict["datePost"]?

Comment: error says that `String` dict["datePost"] can't be converted to `Double`

Comment: I saw that error and it is self explanatory. But can you maybe print it as String and so I can see what you are trying to achieve and try to explain why it is failing.

Comment: I don't think Firebase has native date objects, only Firestore. Perhaps your date is stored as some UTC-type `String` (2018-12-31T18:00:00Z) in Firebase, which would need to be converted into a `Double` using one of Swift's date formatters. But too little info in your post to know what's going on for sure.

Comment: Your datePost object is a string in Firebase. If you open your Firebase console and look at that child node it will look like this *datePost: "12324"* which is a string. That means when it was initially written, it was written as a String. Just write it as an Int (for example) so then in Firebase it will look like this *datePost: 12324* and it will work. However, you should also include better error checking instead of force-unwrapping it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably storing your date values as Strings in Firebase. Just like any other value of type Any, you cannot unwrap the fields themselves as anything but the type they were originally cast as.
Since the field is stored as a String, you can unwrap it as a String and then cast as a Double.

```
if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
    let textPost = dict["post_message"] as! String
    let photoUrlString = dict["photoUrl"] as! String
    let userIDPost = dict["userIDPost"] as! String
    let dateStr = dict["datePost"] as! String
    let datePost = Double(dateStr)
```

Then you can continue on and unwrap the double, then convert to date.

---

Another option, which I personally prefer as a longtime firebase user, is to store dates in firebase as iso8601 formatted strings.

```
let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    let myDate = Date()
    formatter.string(from: myDate)
```

The ISO8601DateFormatter will allow you to convert these strings back to dates in your unwrap like so:

```
if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
    let textPost = dict["post_message"] as! String
    let photoUrlString = dict["photoUrl"] as! String
    let userIDPost = dict["userIDPost"] as! String
    let datePost = dict["datePost"] as! String
    let formatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
    let date = formatter.date(from: datePost)
```

As you can see, this will require fewer steps than recasting as doubles.

However, the real benefit of doing things this way is that ISO8601 dates can be sorted as strings while still keeping your entries sorted by date. In addition, ISO8601 is a universally accepted date format backed by an international standard that will be supported on any platform and in any language, allowing your firebase database to be more versatile and scaleable. On the other hand, Apple's Date(timeIntervalSince1970:) is a customary format from Unix whose adoption has varied across platforms.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @AdautoOliveira Hold up. *Firebase databases only contain String data types* is not accurate. Neither is *you cannot unwrap the fields themselves as anything but Strings*. See [Basic Write Operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#basic_write) which clearly shows storing a lot more than strings in Firebase. Then see [Save data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) which shows Firebase data used as Int's and Bools as well. Storing numbers as strings causes issues with sorting and makes you add unnecessary code.

Comment: Oh - the intention of the answer is good and generally correct but let's ensure the points are accurate. A series of strings "1", "2", "3"..."10", "11" etc will Sort very differently than a series of Ints 1, 2, 3...10, 11 etc. So if you want proper sorting, those objects should be stored as Int's in Firebase, not Strings.

Comment: You’re absolutely right, I’ll update the post to reflect the capabilities of Firebase accurately. As far as force unwrapping vs nil coalescing, that’s not really a point I was trying to make but I agree with everything you said.

Comment: Actually, you forgot to mention that sorting the dates as ISO8601 dates will result in them being in chronological order even when sorted lexicographically as Strings, so I added that as well.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this as a comment but it should probably be an answer as it trips up a lot of folks.

Firebase can store a number of different data types, String, Numbers, Bools and Arrays (please don't use arrays). See the documentation [Basic Write Operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#basic_write)

The problem here is the value being read

```
let datePost = dict["datePost"] as! Double
```

isn't a Double, it's a string in Firebase - that's because it was initially written that way.

```
let aString = "12345"
someNode.setValue(aString)
```

will result in Firebase

```
someNode: "12345"
```

Now when we write an Int like this

```
let anInt = 12345
someNode.setValue(anInt)
```

will result in

```
someNode: 12345
```

There's a big difference between a string that contains a number and a number. Especially in sorting.

```
"1" "2" "3", "10"
```

will sort like this

```
"1", "10", "2", "3"
```

which is obviously not what you would want.

Storing them as numbers 1, 2, 3, 10 and then sorting will result in a correct order.

This can be very important when storing date data as if there are spaces etc in your date (stored as a string) and then you ask Firebase to return a sorted list of nodes by date, it will be all wonky as it's sorting strings, not numbers. Storing your dates as doubles is often best practice.

Lastly, force unwrapping is actually ok as long as you know for 100% certain that every node will contain that type of value, or a value at all. Nil Coalescing is probably a safer bet

```
let datePost = dict["datePost"] as? Double ?? 0
```

meaning that if datePost doesn't exist or isn't a double (or evaluates to nil) 0 is assigned to datePost, preventing your code from blowing up.